# NRPE command not defined

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I have remote server configured with NRPE and it is reporting back successfully for 9 commands however for about 10 others it's giving me the error not defined. Basically I'm attempting to utilize this server as a proxy in order to pull statistics from backend servers not externally reachable. Running the command via command line it functions just fine however when attempting to pull the statistics from the nagios server the first command succeeds and the second command give the following output:

Error:

```
NRPE: Command 'check_remote_users' not defined
```

Works:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_users -w 5 -c 10
```

Doesn't Work:

```
command[check_remote_users]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H hostname -c check_users
```

Also this seems to work as well which is a combination of both:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H hostname -c check_users
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions were correct however my mistake was within the server configuration, it was talking to a different remote host which did not contain the command definitions.